# Capturing timeout error in Google Speech API streaming recognition

Tags: python, grpc, google-speech-api

In a Python program performing streaming speech recognition to Google's Speech API (essentially as detailed [here](https://cloud.google.com/speech/docs/streaming-recognize)), I'm trying to capture the following exception:

> google.api_core.exceptions.InvalidArgument: 400 Client GRPC deadline too short. Should be at least: 3 * audio-duration + 5 seconds. Current deadline is: 189.99934293236583 second(s). Required at least: 196 second(s).

The relevant code block:

```
    with self.MicrophoneStream(self.RATE, self.CHUNK) as stream:
        while True:
            audio_generator = stream.generator()
            requests = (types.StreamingRecognizeRequest(audio_content=content)
                        for content in audio_generator)
            responses = client.streaming_recognize(streaming_config, requests)

            try:
                self.listen_print_loop(responses, self.callback)
                break
            except:
                self.start()
                break
```

Not labeling the exception is functional, except that it makes the program hard to debug, since it causes any exception anywhere to trigger `self.start()`.

I've tried:
- `except StatusCode.INVALID_ARGUMENT  # NameError: name 'StatusCode' is not defined`
- `except google.api_core.exceptions.InvalidArgument  # NameError: name 'google' is not defined`
- `except grpc.RpcError  # no error, just the usual exception above`

Comment: Why isn't adding `from google.api_core import exceptions` at the top of your file and then changing your `except` to `except exceptions.InvalidArgument` the right solution to this problem? (It may or may not be; it's not clear to me that that's something that you already tried.)

Comment: @NathanielManistaAtGoogle This works - I hadn't imported the exceptions correctly. Happy to approve it as the answer if you post it.